# Reading xml data from oracle table column and parsing it in R

Tags: r, xml

I have one scenario in R.
I have connected the oracle database with R through RODBC package and in one column of table there is xml data. Now when I am using xmlParse function its showing error as XML content does not seem to be XML. and class(xmldata) is data frame.

When i am copying the xml data and put it into new xml file and parsing though xmlParse function its getting parsed correctly and class(sourcefile) as XMLInternalDocument.

Comment: when i am saving this oracle table's column data in some variable, its printing with the column name and hence i think this is the reason why its not taking as xml and instead its taking as data.frame

Comment: Pleas show your code. If using `sqlQuery()` then you are importing a dataframe and not specifically the XML content.

Comment: res<- sqlQuery(conn,"Select col1 from table;")                                                                      col1 data in table : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><Data><Sys>ABC</Sys><Event>0123</Event></Data>                 Yes it will save this data in variable res in data.frame format but is there any way i can parse this data though xmlParse()        result1<- xmlParse(res,asText=TRUE)   this is giving me error XML content does not seem to be XML : '1'

Answer (score 0):

Error is raised because you are running `XML::xmlParse` on a dataframe object which is the returned value of `RODBC::sqlQuery()`, and not underlying XML content. Simply index the column and row value for specific XML content.

As example, below reads an XML (top 5 StackOverflow users in R tag) into a dataframe and runs `xmlParse` to reproduce error and another `xmlParse` call to resolve error.

**Dataframe Build** *(replicating sqlQuery)*

```
txt <- '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stackoverflow>
  <group lang="r">
    <topusers>
      <user>akrun</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun</link>
      <location>Bengaluru, Karnataka, India</location>
      <year_rep>15,900</year_rep>
      <total_rep>328,573</total_rep>
      <tag1>r</tag1>
      <tag2>dataframe</tag2>
      <tag3>dplyr</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>Dirk Eddelbuettel</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel</link>
      <location>Chicago, IL, United States </location>
      <year_rep>5,588</year_rep>
      <total_rep>253,481</total_rep>
      <tag1>r</tag1>
      <tag2>rcpp</tag2>
      <tag3>c++</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>42-</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/42</link>
      <location>Alameda, CA</location>
      <year_rep>4,143</year_rep>
      <total_rep>193,407</total_rep>
      <tag1>r</tag1>
      <tag2>dataframe</tag2>
      <tag3>plot</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/a5c1d2h2i1m1n2o1r2t1</link>
      <location>Chennai, India</location>
      <year_rep>3,982</year_rep>
      <total_rep>141,425</total_rep>
      <tag1>r</tag1>
      <tag2>dataframe</tag2>
      <tag3>reshape</tag3>
    </topusers>
    <topusers>
      <user>Gavin Simpson</user>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/429846/gavin-simpson</link>
      <location>Regina, Canada </location>
      <year_rep>2,780</year_rep>
      <total_rep>124,779</total_rep>
      <tag1>r</tag1>
      <tag2>plot</tag2>
      <tag3>dataframe</tag3>
    </topusers>
  </group>
</stackoverflow>'

res <- data.frame(Col1 = txt)
```

**Error line**

```
result1 <- xmlParse(res, asText=TRUE)
# Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: '1'
```

**Resolved line** *(which yields no error)*

```
# SINGLE XML
result1 <- xmlParse(res$Col1[[1]], asText=TRUE)

# MULTIPLE XML (ACROSS ALL ROWS)
result_list <- lapply(res$Col1, xmlParse, asText=TRUE)
```